# Prostate, seminal vesicles or testis which one is bigger(by volume and size)?

Tags: human-anatomy

I can't understand this by looking at these photos, especially the last picture makes me more doubtful.

Do you know which of them is the biggest one by volume?

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Another question is, what is the biggest organ in the male reproductive system? (Note that the bladder is not a part of it.)

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @Bryan-Krause Comparing the size of male reproductive system organs

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of why it matters.

Comment: @BryanKrause  Be sure that I don't want to know this just to satisfy my curiosity, I faced with it in my multiple choice test. I don’t think it matters much what you study anyway.

Comment: I'd note that the images you've examined are representations, not specimens. Generally, don't expect everything to be to scale. I'd suggest Rohan's Color Atlas of Anatomy if you want actual specimens. There is a plate there that should help you.

Comment: @BryanKrause the relative size of anatomical structures is a reasonable question in and of itself. It's useful if, for example, you want to identify them. OP, you've asked two questions: which is bigger, the prostate or the seminal vesicle, and what's the biggest organ. You could improve this question by defining your terms (bigger how? by volume?) and by limiting it to a single question.

Answer (score 3):

The average seminal vesicle length was 31±10.3mm and its average volume 7.1±5.2cc. That is verified by another source which states 6-10mm in [controls](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Representative-photo-of-control-and-PEARKO-seminal-vesicles-A-bar-2-mm-B-Weight-of_fig5_5496735).

The average [prostate volume](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiRmICpz9rgAhUm1-AKHaj6B_IQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fslideplayer.com%2Fslide%2F8252153%2F&psig=AOvVaw2ou4y6POyx-GuIMsJbLLtM&ust=1551312400209542) ranges from 20 to 40cc from ages 30  to 80, 3-2-3cm for younger males 5-4-5 for older ones.